# Почему не обновляются данные в django шаблонах?

Tags: django, postgresql

**views.py**

```
from .model import Video as video

def static_index(request):
    sum = video.objects.aggregate(Sum('chanters'))  
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'sum': sum})
```

**index.html**

```
{{ sum }}
```

**model.py**

```
class Video(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1')
    video = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

Есть страничка, на которой выводятся данные: сумма колонки из одной таблицы с помощью агрегатора. После добавления данных в бд, изменений на страничке не происходит, изменения проискодят только после перегрузки проекта. Шаблонизатор django.

Comment: А если обновлять страницу через Ctrl+Shift+R?

Comment: Не даёт никакого эффекта.

Comment: Во-первых какой кэш настроен? Во-вторых посмотрите в браузере какой ответ - может у вас в браузере кэшируется - проверяйте Cache-Control:"max-age=xx". В консоли тоже посмотрите отдаётся ли ответ. Далее через print проверьте правильные ли значения выдаются от базы

Comment: В settings.py в приложениях никто не переопределяет сервер отладки? Возможно что подключили замену стандартному, в котором есть кеширование. Если очистка кеша не помогает. Декораторы так же могут быть с кешем.